# Magento Connect Manager & ftp write file permissions

Tags: php, magento, ftp, permissions

After transferring my site from development domain to a live domain I have tried to use the magento connect manager to install an extension, however I keep getting:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Please check for sufficient ftp write file permissions.
Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which downloader requires.
```

I have set my folder permissions to be:

```
root: 777

downloader (and recursively into directories only) 777

downloader/config.ini 666

media 777

media/downloadable 777

var 777

app/etc 777

app/code/community 777

var/cache 777
```

I have also used the magento file permissions cleanup tool located at this post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

I have also flushed cache and disabled cache within the site for the moment.

Still no joy! I keep getting the same error message - can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloader and its inner folders permission as `775` and files as `664`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the group and user ownership (of files and folders) will change when moving from one host to another. Make sure that the files are owned and accessible to the web server.