# Magento Permission - I can't add anything via Magento Backend

Tags: php, magento, error-handling, permissions, magento-1.8

Before creating this post I've searched SOF for similar problems but I didn't those advices didn't help me.

Magento Error:
CONNECT ERROR: Please check for sufficient write file permissions.Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which downloader requires.

I have checked 100's times - permissions are right 777 for all the possible folders (var, media, downloader, etc), but still no luck.

At the same time I can download/upload files using FileZilla SFTP - I also can upload for example, images when I work with pages, but only with Chrome and can't do with Safari. Website is currently is on beta version and is accessible only via IP, but I guess this has nothing to do with it.

This:[Magento Connect Manager & ftp write file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452441/magento-connect-manager-ftp-write-file-permissions)
nor this: [Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097724/warning-your-magento-folder-does-not-have-sufficient-write-permissions)
nor this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

didn't help me...

When I was doing last url's advice I got error:

```
sudo chmod o+w var app/etc
chmod: cannot access ‘var’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘app/etc’: No such file or directory
```

Please let me know what I can do to fix this!
Maybe this has something to do with my hosting - Digitalocean?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use full path to this folders and set permissions to subfiles/subfolders too:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /full/path/to/magento/app/etc
sudo chmod -R 775 /full/path/to/magento/var
```

if it still return 'No such file or directory', just create it before:

```
sudo mkdir /full/path/to/magento/app/etc
sudo mkdir /full/path/to/magento/var
```

If this don't help - contact your hosting support, may be web server user is 'nobody' and don't have permissions to folders or something like this.

Comment: I am performing actions under 'root' user - so I guess it has all the possible permissions to perform actions.

So do I just copy paste command or where /full/path/ i suppose to change it to whatever it is? the path actually looks something like this: /var/www/html/magento/app

Comment: Great! Please mark it as answered, it will be useful to others.